# Scons tutorial with an emphasis on fortran

Tags: fortran, scons

When I google for the items in the title, the best I'm finding are some semi-useful, quick-written tutorials. Is there an authoritative scons tutorial (or even better, a book!) that deals with the whole matter - from correct installation, to writing "makefiles". It would be even better if it dealt with some of the fortran aspects (dependencies)?

*p.s. Is this ontopic here, or should have it gone to programmers? On SuperUser it would probably be okey, but I doubt the target population there uses SCons as much as people here.*

---

Edit: *Compiling an example fortran program with modules*

Program source files in `c:\some-project\source\`

```
main.f90 (program)
constants.f90 (module with subroutines)
interpolation.f90 (subroutines)
```

a) build modules
b) build program (so .exe winds up) in `c:\some-project\build\`
c) clean up .obj files afterwards

How to do it with Scons + ifort (or any other compiler - I'll modify the switches afterwards)?

Comment: There are quite a few SCons question on SO, but you may want to consider editing your question to ask something more specific or it may be closed.

Comment: @AndrewWalker - I'll try to include an example case. Would that do?

Answer (score 2):

There are two authoratative references for SCons, the [man page](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html), and the [user guide](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/index.html). To the best of my knowledge there are no published books on SCons.

SCons isn't meant to be hard, in fact it is specifically designed be make doing basic builds simple. In fact, setting up a fortran project should work in exactly the same way as it does for a c project.

```
env = DefaultEnvironment()
env.Program( 'hello-world', ['hello.f','world.f'] )
```

What may change are the environment options that you use to specify options to the compiler. If you are unsure how which options to adjust, you can call `env.Dump()` to get a list of all the keys and associated values inside the environment.

Comment: I know it isn't ment to be hard, but to a lifelong user of plain old make and more recent, of visual studio's ide build system, scons makes so little sense. Needless to say, I don't use python much either. I just wanted some "for dummies" tutorial that shows the main things (from 10000 feet :) Also, if it's in printable format, that's a big plus!